# Using getcwd when running in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

When running a project in eclipse the eclipse saves a copy of the .py file inside the workspace defined in project creation. But the file that imported to project can be in other location.

If using `os.getcwd()` and running the script from the command line, the return value would be the real path of the script file, but when running the script from inside eclipse, the return value would be the path of the workspace, where eclipse saves a copy of the original file.

So the question is, since I run my script during debugging from eclipse, how can I verify that it works before moving to real environment? Is there other way other than `getcwd()`?

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 1):

`os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory.

When running a Python program from Eclipse you can specify what the working directory should be on the Arguments tab of the Run Configuration. This will let you override the value from the project folder (or whatever the default might be.)

[image: Python Run Configurations Arguments tab]